# Shell is not showing text from my prints

Tags: python, shell, menu

I'm trying to create a code for my lists work and i have written this at the moment:

```
list = [ ]

def Menu(choice):
    print("""Menu:


    1.  View entire list

    2.  View one item

    3.  Reset list

    4.  Edit list

    5.  Quit
    """)
    choice = int(input("Please choose an option: "))

while True:
    if choice == "1":
        print (list)
        Menu()

    elif choice == "2":
        oneItem = int(input('Please enter an item to view (1-5): '))
        oneItem = oneItem - 1
        oneView = list[(oneView)]
        print (oneView)
        Menu()

    elif choice == "3":
        list = [None]*6
        Menu()    

    elif choice == "4":
        def carryon():
            for i in range(6):
                add = input("Please enter a new item for the list: ")
                list.append(add)
                carryOn = input("Would you like to carry on? (y/n): ")
                if carryOn == "y":
                    carryon()
                else:
                    break
                break  
        Menu()
```

When I run the code in shell the menu appears fine:

```
Menu:


1.  View entire list

2.  View one item

3.  Reset list

4.  Edit list

5.  Quit

Please choose an option: 3
```

But then it just comes up blank. I can type things in still but nothing happens. Even after i press enter it just carries on. I use python 3.4 (gui)

Comment: Fix your formatting

Comment: The code you posted is obviously not the code you're running - else you'd get a `TypeError` on the first call to `Menu()`.

Comment: Also `Menu()    elif choice == "4":` is a SyntaxError. And once that's fixed, you get `NameError: name 'choice' is not defined`.

Comment: Your `Menu` function needs to return the choice to the calling code, and that code needs to save the choice.